# Display UserName and Role in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create an easy Admin panel for editing users roles. First I want to display users list with their roles.

First I edited some things in AccountModel:

Context:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }
}
```

User profile:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }
}
```

User roles:

```
[Table("webpages_Roles")]
public class UserRole
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

After that I created UserController with ActionResult Index:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var db = new UsersContext())
    {
        return View(db.UserProfiles.Include("UserRole").ToList());
    }
}
```

And View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AnimeWeb.Models.UserProfile>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        User Name
    </th>

    <th>
        User Role
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserRole)
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Partial View for UserRole looks like this:

```
@model AnimeWeb.Models.UserRole

<tr>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RoleName),
</tr>
```

When I try to execute it I get InnerException error: "Invalid object name 'dbo.UserRoleUserProfiles'.". I dont quite get it. Could someone explain me why is this happening and how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you ever need to navigate from `UserRole` to `UserProfile` through the `ICollection<UserProfile>`?  Consider removing this collection.  That said, your error message mentions `UserProfiles` where this collection is named `UserProfile`.  Could be a misspelling somewhere?

Comment: After deleting 'ICollection<UserProfile>' i get error: 'Invalid column name 'UserProfile_UserId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserProfile_UserId'.'

Comment: Seems like the database would need to be regenerated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem lies here

```
public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }
```

And you don't have a mapping for these classes, so the default setting creates a `UserRoleUserProfiles` table(or class) and it doesn't exist in the database, so the problem occurs.

You can try remove this line of code and then try run the project again

Comment: If I delete that line I get that specified include path is not valid. But I need it or I will get "Data has been disposed before connection was complete".

Comment: Have you considered using mappings? [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/), [Fluent NHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/), [Entity Framework Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)